# Language Specific Extensions for Karate

Tags: karate

Given Karate is Categorised as Java Only Framework , Can we have language specific extensions , so that these tests can sit along with APP Code where ever needed.

Similar to PACT framework

Regards
Bheem

Answer (score 1):

There are (in my opinion) a few mis-conceptions in your questions, so I'll try and address them as well as provide an answer.

> Karate is Categorised as Java Only Framework

Karate is indeed *implemented* in Java but you write tests in a language-neutral syntax (Gherkin) - and you typically work with request and response payloads as pure JSON. And for the business of testing web-services, the language actually should not matter at all - as long as you speak HTTP and JSON - and isn't that the whole point of web-services.

> Can we have language specific extensions

And to add to the points I made above, you really don't need any language specific extensions. Karate is actually used by many .NET, Python and JS teams - because all you need is the JRE (not even the JDK) - and the [stand-alone executable](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#standalone-jar) allows you to run tests and even generate the CI-compatible reports. For an example of a demo project that you can try (in a few minutes) that will run cross-platform, take a look at this: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-sikulix-demo

> tests can sit along with APP Code

Yes, Karate tests are plain-text and you can check them in alongside your app-server code, and many teams do this. Yes, if it is a Java Maven or Gradle project - it is a little simpler to integrate into a build or CI job - but that is where the stand-alone CLI starts to shine.

> Similar to PACT framework

You mean you want to simply implement Consumer Driven Contract tests ? Take a look at this project: https://github.com/ptrthomas/payment-service - which in my humble opinion demonstrates how Karate does CDC far more elegantly and simpler than Pact (disclaimer, I'm the dev of Karate). It is worth repeating that Karate is plain text, language-neutral and can be run via a cross-platform CLI that generates reports (JUnit XML) compatible with all CI tools. Sharing of tests (or if you want to call them contracts) across teams - is best done via Git without having to re-invent the wheel for collaboration, concurrent development and versioning.